# UV unwrap, Checker straight vs UV straight (Multiple Question)

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]  [image]

Regarding the images, I tend to priorities checker straight over UV straight. However, recently I came across client that want all the UV to be straight like the 2nd image shown. As it shown, the UV clearly stretched. However,  this does seem to cause any concern when I brought it up. Long story short, now I wondering which is more important , checker straight or uv straight?

1. Is there any criteria on which model should be UV straight vs checker straight ? Like organic model(face, skin, cloth) vs Inorganic object (wall, box ,etc)
2. I came across some discussion stating "straight UV" is much better for tiling and due to the pixel is being a cube is much more better for the UV to be straight. Not sure if this is true?
3. Checker straight vs UV straight, which is more important?. I usually go for checker straight to prevent distortion

Comment: what did your client tell you to justify that straight UVs were better in that case? It seems weird

Comment: "easier to pack and for reusing texture". I left out some details,  stuff like tree are fine for not being fully straight,  but  model with sharp edged such as window frame door etc . all require to be straight. I was so confuse when I received the feedback, as this the 1st time I heard of such requirement.

 I though this is one of those industry requirement at 1st, but I cant seem to find any article proving my assumption....

Comment: well, it seems to me that the non-straight unwrap is the one that will give you reusable textures as they won't be stretched, I hope someone who knows a bit game industry will understand

Comment: me too, I genuinely surprise there is not much discussion related to this topic.

Comment: i agree with @moonboots as whilst straight UVs can be useful for tessellating 2D planes, on 3D objects like these, straight UVs will just lead to horrendous stretching which you can see from your example. Your client isn't confusing lightmaps with UV maps are they?

Comment: Seems like a miscommunication.  You can have 'straight' UVs without stretching but you need a lot more geometry to make it work.

Comment: I cant really tell if it is miscommunication or not,  as the client approved and accepted my uv(straight UV) by the time I'm writing this. It just feel really weird by the whole request as this goes against, the things I have been taught regarding UV unwrapping. I guess just to shown the industry is weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no rules for how a 3D model should be, only reasons to make one decision over another.

Your "checker straight" UV map is a a UV map that minimizes distortion.  If we use that to create a texture, we'll have even texel density.  Differences in how different engines triangulate the faces will create minimal artifacts (probably none in your example.)  Those are all good features.

Your "UV straight" UV map doesn't have those features.  It has uneven texel density, and triangulation artifacts are probably already apparent in the middle of the faces.  Try using a wave texture:

[image]

What it *does* have going for it:

1. It is easier to create some textures for it.
2. We might be able to create materials or textures for it that involve re-use between different models.
3. We may be using UV for an "unlabelled" purpose, in which case everything about texturing goes out the window.

These are less apparent in the model you've given as an example than they would be elsewhere.  But consider a character model's hair.  If we use the second UV map, we have consistent tangents for anisotropy across different hair meshes.

However, that doesn't mean that those are the client's reasons.  Sometimes, people want things because they don't know what they should want.  3D graphics are complicated, and if somebody is commissioning untextured work with specific UVs, they probably don't understand it very well.  You might consider offering *both* UV maps on the model in this case.  You do what the client wants.  Not because "the customer is always right", they are very frequently wrong, but just because if you don't, you won't get any repeat business.

To explicitly answer your questions (I missed these the first read, or else they were an edit):

1. The criterion is not the model, but how you want to texture the model.
2. No, that's not true.  There are no rendering artifacts created by "checker straight" UV that aren't worse in "UV straight" UV.  With texture filtering, necessary to eliminate moire artifacts, the renderer won't be sampling single texels anyways.
3. If nobody specifies, and you are creating a textured model, you should give "checker straight" UV, which will create the fewest artifacts.  If you are creating an untextured model, then the client will probably have specific UV needs that depend upon how they wish to texture the model, or else they'll be using a texture artist that will end up creating their own UVs for texturing purposes anyways.